# what is the unit of measurement in height and width of Qwidget in Qt

Tags: qt, widget, height, width

I want to plot in Qt using `QCustomPlot`. I draw a widget and promote it to `QCustomPlot`. Now I want to set height and width of the widget in millimeter. How can I do this action?

Answer (score 2):

This is a hard one cause the actual on screen size of component is very platform dependent. Below you have two articles from Qt documentation about getting size of a widget and screen geometry for some specific platforms.

[Screen geometry](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdesktopwidget.html#screen-geometry)

[Window geometry](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/application-windows.html#window-geometry)

Maybe You will find this usefull